# MFC: Is there an event to detect when a CDockablePane derived window has been opened either by sliding out or showing?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I want to delay initialization of a CDockablePane derived window until the window is actually shown. If the window is simply docked then WM_SHOWWINDOW is pretty effective but when the window is in AutoHideMode WM_SHOWWINDOW is unpredictable and I can't see an event that indicates that the slide out has finished.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've chosen is to override the virtual methods `CDockablePane::ShowPane` for when `IsAutoHideMode()` is `FALSE` and `CDockablePane::OnSlide` for when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Try override CDockablePane::CheckStopSlideCondition, save bSlideDirection and the return value of the base class implementation somewhere

override CDockablePane::OnTimer and check the saved values after the base class implementation when nIDEvent is AFX_AUTO_HIDE_SLIDE_OUT_EVENT:

Note: AFX_AUTO_HIDE_SLIDE_OUT_EVENT is not documented and may be unavailable in future versions of MFC

Comment: Thanks for the time, although I don't think this is quite the right solution. I've added an answer.